# rails geocoder near scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, geolocation, geocoding

Is there a way to get, for example, ten nearest places, no matter how big distance from object is?

```
Obj.near(@address, 10)
```

And this scope should return 10 nearest places, not objects within radius 10.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest taking a look at [GeoRuby](http://georuby.rubyforge.org/) and [spatial_adapter](https://github.com/fragility/spatial_adapter). Unless you want to load a lot of data from your database and then doing the distance comparison yourself I'd suggest that you use PostgreSQL as your DB engine, as it has great Geo/GIS support. Putting the three together means that assuming you can pass a GeoRuby object as your @address, a scope approximatly like the following would do the job you need

```
scope :near lambda { |location, count| order("ST_Distance(geom_field_in_table, ST_GeomFromWKB(#{location.as_wkb}, -1))").limit(count) }
```